# How to retrieve location on click of a button

Tags: android, locationmanager, android-location, locationlistener

I want to be able to do this:

I have a `TextView` and a `Button`. When I click on the `Button`, the text of the `TextView` should be set to the name of my current locality.

I found some examples that use the `LocationManager` and `LocationListener` but it seems the `LocationListener` listens for `onLocationChanged`.

Any ideas on how to achieve what I want to do?

Comment: have u checked in your device that GPS location is on or not

Comment: onLocationChanged will work, since it will get your first location which you can store as a variable. If you move it will update, if not there is no need to update as you already have your stored location.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the google map api to get the current location and then print the address of that location from the given lat long. i know its not detail answer but sure that it will be provide you the hint to start the solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this it's the best way to do this........

LocationManager mLocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                LocationListener mLocListener = new MyLocationListener();
                mLocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mLocListener);

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{

```
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {           
        String message = String.format(
                    "New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                    location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()
            );
            Toast.makeText(LbsGeocodingActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {

    }
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }       
}
```

Comment: `onLocationChanged` doesn't seem to get executed, so I do not receive any location updates. And I have tried exactly as you have up there.

Comment: I tried this solution too which yours is almost like http://stackoverflow.com/a/10917500/1319753. Same issue: `onLocationChanged` doesn't seem to get executed ever. What am I not doing?